# Polyvariadic functions with polymorphic result value

Tags: haskell, polyvariadic

I'm trying to implement a Pascal-style `write` procedure in Haskell as a polyvariadic function. Here is a simplified version with monomorphic result type (`IO` in that case) that works fine:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import System.IO


class WriteParams a where
    writeParams :: IO () -> a

instance (a ~ ()) => WriteParams (IO a) where
    writeParams = id

instance (Show a, WriteParams r) => WriteParams (a -> r) where
    writeParams m a = writeParams (m >> putStr (show a ++ " "))

write :: WriteParams params => params
write = writeParams (return ())

test :: IO ()
test = do
    write 123
    write ('a', 'z') True
```

When changing the result type to a polymorphic type, however, to use that function in different monads that have a `MonadIO` instance, I'm running into overlapping or undecidable instances. Specifically, that `a ~ ()` trick from the previous version doesn't work anymore. The best approach is the following which requires a lot of type annotations, though:

```hs
class WriteParams' m a where
    writeParams' :: m () -> a

instance (MonadIO m, m ~ m') => WriteParams' m (m' ()) where
    writeParams' m = m

instance (MonadIO m, Show a, WriteParams' m r) => WriteParams' m (a -> r) where
    writeParams' m a = writeParams' (m >> liftIO (putStr $ show a ++ " "))

write' :: forall m params . (MonadIO m, WriteParams' m params) => params
write' = writeParams' (return () :: m ())

test' :: IO ()
test' = do
    write' 123 () :: IO ()
    flip runReaderT () $ do
        write' 45 ('a', 'z') :: ReaderT () IO ()
        write' True
```

Is there anyway to make this example work without having to add type annotations here and there and still keep the result type polymorphic?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `Text.Printf` (which, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do here, does exactly this?)

Comment: I suspect if you want good type inference you're going to have to make one instance of `WriteParams` for each existing instance of `MonadIO` -- or at least one for each `MonadIO` instance you care about using. You can make this less tedious by giving a default, so that you need only write e.g. `instance (MonadIO m, a ~ ()) => WriteParams (ReaderT r m a)` and don't need to give the `where` block, but... yeah, a bit annoying.

Comment: @Cubic My use case is more complex that `printf`, I just simplified it a bit in the example so that they may look similar

Comment: @DanielWagner That's a pretty simple but effective idea, I haven't thought of. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve the generalization of `test` that Li-yao Xia mentioned in their answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have added an answer fleshing out my comment; perhaps you could object with a concrete code snippet that doesn't work well with that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two instances overlap, because their indices unify: `m' () ~ (a -> r)` with `m' ~ (->) a` and `() ~ r`.

To pick the first instance whenever `m'` is not a function type, you can add an `OVERLAPPING` pragma. ([Read more about it in the GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overlapping-instances))

```
-- We must put the equality (a ~ ()) to the left to make this
-- strictly less specific than (a -> r)
instance (MonadIO m, a ~ ()) => WriteParams (m a) where
    writeParams = liftIO 

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Show a, WriteParams r) => WriteParams (a -> r) where
    writeParams m a = writeParams (m >> putStr (show a ++ " "))
```

---

However, the overlapping instance makes it inconvenient to use `write` in a context where the monad is a parameter `m` (try generalizing the signature of `test`).

There is a way to avoid overlapping instances by using closed type families, to define a type-level boolean that's true if and only if a given type is a function type, so that instances can match on it. See below.

It arguably just looks like more code and more complexity, but, on top of the added expressiveness (we can have a generalized `test` with a `MonadIO` constraint), I think this style makes the logic of the instances clearer in the end by isolating the pattern-matching on types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import System.IO


class WriteParams a where
    writeParams :: IO () -> a

instance WriteParamsIf a (IsFun a) => WriteParams a where
    writeParams = writeParamsIf

type family IsFun a :: Bool where
  IsFun (m c) = IsFun1 m
  IsFun a = 'False

type family IsFun1 (f :: * -> *) :: Bool where
  IsFun1 ((->) b) = 'True
  IsFun1 f = 'False

class (isFun ~ IsFun a) => WriteParamsIf a isFun where
  writeParamsIf :: IO () -> a

instance (Show a, WriteParams r) => WriteParamsIf (a -> r) 'True where
  writeParamsIf m a = writeParams (m >> putStr (show a ++ " "))

instance ('False ~ IsFun (m a), MonadIO m, a ~ ()) => WriteParamsIf (m a) 'False where
  writeParamsIf = liftIO

write :: WriteParams params => params
write = writeParams (return ())

test :: (MonadIO m, IsFun1 m ~ 'False) => m ()
test = do
    write 123
    write ('a', 'z') True

main = test  -- for ghc to compile it
```

---

### Some words on `UndecidableInstances`

Undecidable instances are an orthogonal feature to overlapping instances, and in fact I think they're much less controversial. Whereas badly using `OVERLAPPING` may cause incoherence (constraints being solved differently in different contexts), badly using `UndecidableInstances` may at worst send the compiler in a loop (in practice GHC terminates with an error message once some threshold is reached), which is still bad but when it does manage to resolve instances it is still guaranteed that the solution is unique.

`UndecidableInstances` lifts limitations that made sense a long time ago, but are now too restrictive to work with the modern extensions to type classes.

In practice, most common type classes and instances defined with `UndecidableInstances`, including the one above, still guarantee that their resolution will terminate. In fact, [there is an active proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/114) for a new instance termination checker. (I don't know yet whether it handles this case here.)

Comment: Thank you, that sems to be pretty much what I was looking for. One thing that scares me a bit is the use of undecidable instances. I already tried to avoid overlapping instances as I was told they could lead to inconsitent behaviour. Aren't undecidable instances even worse then? Or are they okay when used with closed type families (I've never used the latter ones before)?

Comment: I added a few words about undecidable instances in my answer. The short answer is that they're much more safe than overlapping instances because they don't break type class coherence.

Comment: Overlapping instances are also not problematic when they are all defined in the same module, as is the case here. It's just that they might be better received with a proper mechanism in the language to restrict their usage.

Answer (score 2):

Here I flesh out my comment into an answer. We will keep the idea of your original class, and even the existing instances, only adding instances. Simply add one instance for each existing `MonadIO` instance; I'll do just one to illustrate the pattern.

```
instance (MonadIO m, a ~ ()) => WriteParams (ReaderT r m a) where
    writeParams = liftIO
```

Everything works fine:

```
main = do
    write 45
    flip runReaderT () $ do
        write 45 ('a', 'z')
        write "hi"
```

This prints `45 45 ('a','z') "hi"` when executed.

If you would like to reduce the `writeParams = liftIO` boilerplate a little bit, you can turn on `DefaultSignatures` and add:

```
class WriteParams a where
    writeParams :: IO () -> a
    default writeParams :: (MonadIO m, a ~ m ()) => IO () -> a
    writeParams = liftIO
```

Then the `IO` and `ReaderT` instances are just:

```
instance a ~ () => WriteParams (IO a)
instance (MonadIO m, a ~ ()) => WriteParams (ReaderT r m a)
```

Comment: There is a trailing space after ... in the "This prints ... when executed." sentence that the Markdown parser appears to be eating. If you know how to get it to appear, please let me know and I'll edit the answer to be slightly more precise.

Comment: What I meant in my earlier comment is Li-yao Xia's idea of generalizing the type of `test` to yield something like `(MonadIO m, ...) => m ()` which would be nice but doesn't seems to be possible with this version